# Search from particular string from file in Unix which has same pattern for other subdirectory

Tags: shell, unix, aix

I have requirement for Unix-AIX to find string(filename.date.dat) from Parameter file of Informatica for same directory structures we have but I don't want to search in other directories which are similar level of ParmFiles directory.

Here are directory structure

```
   /infapp/infpqwe/ParmFiles/Parameter Files
   /infapp/infdpoi/ParmFiles/Parameter Files 
   /infapp/infprty/ParmFiles/Parameter Files
   /infapp/infdhgt/ParmFiles/Parameter Files
```

Don't want to search inside which has lots of data

```
   /infapp/infpqwe/TgtDir/
   /infapp/infdpoi/TgtDir/
```

Thank you in advance for help !! and quick resolution highly appreciate !!!

Thanks,
LR

Answer (score 0):

Try using wildcards so

```
grep "filename.dat.dat" /infapp/*/ParmFiles/"Parameter Files"*
```

Comment: For some reason stackoverflow is removing stars from my posting... there's supposed to be a star between // and another one at the end

Comment: You needed to click on `{}`.

Comment: Use double quotes: Now it will try to grep `/infapp/*/ParmFiles/Parameter` and also grep from `Files*`.  I think you want to grep from `/infapp/*/ParmFiles/"Parameter Files"/*`.